# xpages ftsearch into a categorized sorted viewpanel

Tags: xpages

using this tutorial ( altough, I did some minor changes ): http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesViewControlAddFullTextSearch.htm .

My search is OK, and also, the search results are displayed correctly for a plat view ( uncategorized ).

I would like to display my search results ( docs. ) inside a categorzied + sorted ( ascending ) viewPanel which lists some docs. having 2 `formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");` different values.

Indeed, the search is working fine, but when I display the results into my viewPanel, the first column ( which is categorized and sorted ascending ) is missing ... and so the link between the resulted docs ( these docs. are linked by a common field ) is gone.

How can I resolve this issue?

My guess is that there are some certain rows which don't represent a Document ( these docs. are represented by the 1st column categorized ) ... and because of it, the FTsearch don't display those specific rows.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As in normal categorized views in the Notes client, search results won't be displayed with categories. As the view control uses the same data and collection as source the same behavior will be used in Xpages views.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to roll your own and then use a repeat or data table. Do your full text search in code (Java or SSJS) and then loop through the results and build an array list of objects. Each object could hold what you want to display in the columns.

Howard